# Speeding up opening of hyperlinks defined with openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-2.7, excel-2010, openpyxl

I am adding hyperlinks to cells in an xlsm using `openpyxl` by setting the `.hyperlink` attribute on each cell in question. When I save in `openpyxl` and reopen the spreadsheet in Excel, the hyperlinks are present and correct.

The thing is: when clicked, there is a lag of approximately 5 seconds before a new tab is opened in a browser. Contrast this to clicking on a hyperlink added manually in Excel, where the page loads (or rather the new tab opens) instantaneously when clicked.

What causes this 5 second lag, and is there a way to reduce or it do away with it?

Comment: Could be a number of things. One of the things that Excel likes to do is cache stuff. openpyxl does no caching (of formulae results, or chart data, or data from other sources) so there is sometimes a lag while Excel gets or calculates data. The implementation of hyperlinks isn't brilliant but I think a bit better in 2.3.

Comment: OK. If you could point me to the relevant commits at https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/branch/2.3 I'll take a look to consider upgrading.